# Error in While LOOP: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am trying to write a program using a while loop:

(UPDATE: solution founded!! since there must be a true/false statement provided in the below part), The if function should be clear justification.

```
while ((it_count) < it_max && it_change > tol)
     {

    wj <- Kc%*%yj               #LS regression for wj
    vj <- wj/as.vector(t(wj)%*%wj)      #normalization of wj
    cj <- t(yj)%*%vj            #LS regression for cj
    old_yj <- yj
    yj <- yj%*%cj
    yj <- yj/as.vector(t(yj)%*%yj)      #normalize new yj
    diff_y <- yj - old_yj
    it_change <- diff_y/as.vector(t(diff_y)%*%diff_y)
    it_count <- inc(it_count)
     }

    if (a == j ) break 
    else 
    {warning(paste("failed to converge for component", a, "steps"))}
```

Comment: You only need a single `&` character for the AND opetator

Comment: @Rohit: `&&` works differently to a single `&`, as it returns only a single result even when you apply it to vectors. It's often a better choice for `if` clauses.

Comment: Yes and no, the single `&` does element-wise comparisons and thus return a n-length logical vector, while double `&&` will always return a single TRUE/FALSE by evaluating left-to-right the first element. Neither will however change the error presented here.

Comment: The error occurs because one of the variables in `(it_count) < it_max && it_change > tol` is an `NA`, thus either comparison evalutes to `NA`, which is neither TRUE nor FALSE.

Comment: hello all, I provided the full code that used in the algorithm

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara - comparisons (`>` and `<`) takes precendence over and and or (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), so it shouldn't change the outcome. But it could improve readability.

Comment: @Honstel But you not gave example data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Beside of that your code is not minimal; [mcve]

Comment: why dont you satrt by cleaning your code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though something about your condition in the while statement isn't returning a TRUE or a FALSE like it should. From the chunk of code you've shared, it doesn't tell us how `it_max` or `tol` is defined. Given it runs but returns something that isn't a TRUE or FALSE, I suspect one (or both) of them are an `NA` or `NULL`. Make sure they're declared and this should work.

If it still doesn't work, upload the code where these are declared and we can help more.